# What are the recommended settings for fast queue binding in a RabbitMQ cluster

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp

When binding a queue in a RabbitMQ cluster with *com.rabbit.mq:amqp-client:5.4.3*, this takes a considerable amount of time when many queues are bound to an exchange within a short duration (averaging to ca. *1 second*, with max times reaching *10 seconds*). The RabbitMQ cluster is running 3 nodes in version *3.7.8* (*Erlang 20.3.4*) inside Rancher/Kubernetes.

When reducing the number of nodes down to a single node, maximum times stay well below 1 second (*<700 ms*. Still somewhat long, if you ask me, but acceptable). With a single node, average times range between *10 and 100 milliseconds*.

I understand that replicating this information between the cluster nodes can take some time, but *1 to 2 orders of magnitude worse* performance with just 3 nodes? (the same happens with 2 nodes as well, but 3 nodes is the minimum for a meaningful cluster setup)

Are there some knobs to turn to bring the time to bind a queue to an *acceptable* level for a cluster? Is there a configuration I'm missing? Having only a single node is a non-option with HA in mind. I couldn't find anything helpful in https://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html until now, maybe I missed it?

**TLDR**:

- Are these timings expected for a RabbitMQ cluster?
- What is the performance one can expect from a simple RabbitMQ (3 nodes) when binding queues to exchanges?

  - How many "bind" operations can be performed in e.g. 1 second?
  - Which factors affect this? Number of exchanges, number of queues, number of existing bindings, frequency of the operation?
- What are the options to reduce the time required to create bindings?

Comment: You should ask such questions on the rabbitmq-users Google group - the rabbit team monitors that more often then Stack Overflow.

Comment: Corresponding Google groups thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rabbitmq-users/tFfPugdWsic – I will copy useful answers here, so future visitors can easily find the answer on the knowledge base that is Stackoverflow